# How can I pass additional arguments into pandas's apply function?

Tags: pandas

If my dataFrame's some column string values need to be normalized with the delimiter '|'. For example, the column name's values 'a/b/c' that need to be normalized to 'a|b|c'. And 'sex' columns 'M/F' needs to be normalized to 'M|F'.

```
columns_to_be_normalized = ['name', 'sex']
delimiters = ['/', ';', ',']      
for column in columns_to_be_normalized:
   df[column] = df[column].apply(normalize)

def normalize(column_text):
    for delimiter in delimiters:
        normalized_column_text = re.sub(delimiter, '|', text)
        if column_text != normalized_column_text:
            return normalized
     return column_text
```

My question is, how do I pass the variable delimiters into the normalize function so that I can use it in the regex? The reason I have to pass it as an argument is because the delimiters could change depending on some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `normalize` with a named parameter:

```
def normalize(column_text, delimiters=None):
    if delimiters is None:
        delimiters = ['/'] # define the default here
    for delimiter in delimiters:
        normalized_column_text = re.sub(delimiter, '|', text)
        if column_text != normalized_column_text:
            return normalized # this should be fixed
     return column_text
```

Then use:

```
df[column] = df[column].apply(normalize, delimiters=['/', ';', ','])
```

Note that you don't need `apply` per item though. You can directly use pandas `str.replace` that takes care of the loop for you:

```
import re
delimiters = ['/', ';', ',']
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))

df[columns_to_be_normalized] = (
df[columns_to_be_normalized].apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(regex, '|', regex=True))
)
```

Comment: vectorize and pandas string operations in the same sentence :)

Comment: mozway, why do you put the vectorized df into an external ()?

Comment: @marlon just a habit in case more commands need to be added while keeping them on several lines. I don't really like to use `\` to break a command on several lines

Comment: So the s.str.replace() is a pandas function, not the python 'replace', right?

Comment: @marlon correct

Comment: Btw, I'm changing a bit my answer as "vectorize" was meant in the sense "no need to write a loop", rather than "simultaneous low level operation", which can be misleading as hinted by @sammywemmy

Comment: Good to know the change.